# Passenger + Rails 3.1.1 = Could not find rake-0.9.2 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rake, passenger

I know there are already some threads about this error, but none of them solved my problem.
I started a new rails app with rails 3.1.1 and RVM Ruby 1.9.2-p180.
It works when I use `rails server` and go to localhost:3000

But when I try to host it like my other Rails 3.0.x apps using Passenger (OSX pref pane)
and visit it in the browser I get the following error:

```
    Error message:
    Could not find rake-0.9.2 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
    Exception class:
    PhusionPassenger::UnknownError
```

Anybody else experiencing problems with rails 3.1.1 and passenger?

when I type `gem list --local` there is definitely rake 0.9.2 in my list, and I am also in the correct RVM gemset.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First check if Passenger is using correct ruby (if you use Apache):

```
LoadModule passenger_module /home/user/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03/gems/passenger-3.0.9/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so
PassengerRoot /home/user/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03/gems/passenger-3.0.9
PassengerRuby /home/user/.rvm/wrappers/ree-1.8.7-2011.03/ruby
```

Then check [RVM + passenger](http://rvm.io/integration/passenger) guide.

Comment: +1 Thanks you! I was so frustrated until I read this question