# Ubuntu | Passenger | Rails - Could not find rake-0.9.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, bundler, passenger, linode

I`ve managed to deploy the application to a Linode server, boot up apache & get to the index page. However everything beyond that throws the error below:

```
Error message:
Could not find rake-0.9.2 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
Exception class:
PhusionPassenger::UnknownError

0   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/bundler-1.2.2/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb  90  in `block in materialize'
1   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/bundler-1.2.2/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb  83  in `map!'
2   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/bundler-1.2.2/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb  83  in `materialize'
3   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/bundler-1.2.2/lib/bundler/definition.rb    113 in `specs'
4   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/bundler-1.2.2/lib/bundler/definition.rb    158 in `specs_for'
5   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/bundler-1.2.2/lib/bundler/definition.rb    147 in `requested_specs'
6   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/bundler-1.2.2/lib/bundler/environment.rb   23  in `requested_specs'
7   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/bundler-1.2.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb   11  in `setup'
8   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/bundler-1.2.2/lib/bundler.rb   116 in `setup'
9   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/passenger-3.0.18/lib/phusion_passenger/utils.rb    326 in `prepare_app_process'
10  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/passenger-3.0.18/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb 156 in `block in initialize_server'
11  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/passenger-3.0.18/lib/phusion_passenger/utils.rb    563 in `report_app_init_status'
12  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/passenger-3.0.18/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb 154 in `initialize_server'
13  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/passenger-3.0.18/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb  204 in `start_synchronously'
14  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/passenger-3.0.18/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb  180 in `start'
15  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/passenger-3.0.18/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb 129 in `start'
16  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/passenger-3.0.18/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb    253 in `block (2 levels) in spawn_rack_application'
17  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/passenger-3.0.18/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb   132 in `lookup_or_add'
18  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/passenger-3.0.18/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb    246 in `block in spawn_rack_application'
19  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/passenger-3.0.18/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb   82  in `block in synchronize'
20      prelude>    10:in `synchronize'
21  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/passenger-3.0.18/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb   79  in `synchronize'
22  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/passenger-3.0.18/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb    244 in `spawn_rack_application'
23  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/passenger-3.0.18/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb    137 in `spawn_application'
24  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/passenger-3.0.18/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb    275 in `handle_spawn_application'
25  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/passenger-3.0.18/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb  357 in `server_main_loop'
26  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/passenger-3.0.18/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb  206 in `start_synchronously'
27  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/passenger-3.0.18/helper-scripts/passenger-spawn-server 99  in `'
```

I've found that someone was having a similar issue here on SO, however I`v managed to follow the steps in the referred url but that doesn't change anything.

[Passenger + Rails 3.1.1 = Could not find rake-0.9.2 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7833020/passenger-rails-3-1-1-could-not-find-rake-0-9-2-in-any-of-the-sources-bundl)

I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score -1):

Try running

```
bundle install
```

That should install all the gems your app requires, which should also include Rake -v 0.9.2