# Apache, Ruby (not RVM), Passenger LoadPath - (Bundler::GemNotFound)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, apache, passenger, gitlab

I'm on an AWS Micro instance using Ruby 1.9.3p327, RubyGems 1.8.23 and Passenger 3.

My server (when I'm not taking it down trying to fix things) is at http://shaanan.cohney.info/gitlab/

I'm attempting to install Gitlab onto Apache2.

It all goes well up to the point where I try and deploy the installation via passenger.

I get the error:

```
Could not find multi_json-1.5.0 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)

/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.0/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb   95  in `block in materialize'
```

My load path that I have printed is:

```
["/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.19/lib", "/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.0/lib", "/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1", "/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux", "/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby", "/usr/local/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.9.1", "/usr/local/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux", "/usr/local/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby", "/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1", "/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux"]
```

Which is missing the directory where my gems are installed.

I've searched around online but have not yet been able to figure out a fix after trying multiple things.

The error appears when I visit myhostname.com/gitlab

My current guess is that it has something to do with the user for whom I installed ruby, vs the user of the application, vs the user passenger is running as.

UPDATE: I have upgraded to the beta version of passenger to see if it would make a difference. On error it gives me my environment as follows:

```
APACHE_PID_FILE = /var/run/apache2.pid
SHELL = /bin/bash
APACHE_RUN_USER = www-data
PASSENGER_DEBUG_DIR = /tmp/passenger.spawn-debug.27672-140235446962704
USER = gitlab
APACHE_LOG_DIR = /var/log/apache2
PATH = /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
PWD = /home/gitlab/gitlab
APACHE_RUN_GROUP = www-data
LANG = C
SHLVL = 0
HOME = /home/gitlab
LOGNAME = gitlab
APACHE_LOCK_DIR = /var/lock/apache2
APACHE_RUN_DIR = /var/run/apache2
IN_PASSENGER = 1
PYTHONUNBUFFERED = 1
RAILS_ENV = production
RACK_ENV = production
WSGI_ENV = production
PASSENGER_ENV = production
RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT = production
RACK_BASE_URI = production
PASSENGER_BASE_URI = production
REQUEST_METHOD = GET
SERVER_PORT = 80
SERVER_ADDR = 10.244.35.233
QUERY_STRING = 
SERVER_PROTOCOL = HTTP/1.1
REMOTE_PORT = 4789
REMOTE_ADDR = 72.13.132.134
REQUEST_URI = /gitlab/
SERVER_SOFTWARE = Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
DOCUMENT_ROOT = /var/www/
SERVER_NAME = shaanan.cohney.info
GEM_PATH = 
SERVER_ADMIN = webmaster@localhost
BUNDLE_GEMFILE = /home/gitlab/gitlab/Gemfile
_ORIGINAL_GEM_PATH = /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392
GEM_HOME = /home/gitlab/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1
```

I've also noted that _ORIGINAL_GEM_PATH is set to an RVM value from when I had it installed.

Comment: Do you mean you get the error message when typing "gem install passenger"?

Comment: as I updated above, it happens after I deploy the site and visit the URL.

Comment: As in http://stackoverflow.com/a/7833096/6309 are you using the right ruby?

Comment: Check also your `bundle install` process (http://stackoverflow.com/a/9147605/6309) and your `rvm_lib_path` (http://blog.ninjahideout.com/posts/the-path-to-better-rvm-and-passenger-integration)

Comment: I've removed all versions of Ruby bar one from my system to try and make it easier.  I'm not sure what you mean by  `rv=_lib_path` but I tried using RVM previously with the same error, and so now I'm just on a standard Ruby install.

Comment: oh and have been using `sudo -u git -H bundle install --deployment --without development test postgres`

Comment: Ok. Just FYI, here is my httpd.conf file for a passenger-gitlab installation: https://github.com/VonC/compileEverything/blob/master/apache/env.conf.tpl#L190-L228 (it is a template fiel, hence the `@xxx@` in it)

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a play with it and see if it helps!